# HTML Email Design with Nested Tables

Tags: html, html-table, nested, html-email

Why isn't my `text-decoration="none"` appearing properly? I've tried putting it in different locations, such as `table`, `tr`, `td`, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any common mistakes in styling email designs? Here is my code:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" max-width="100%" width="600px" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>

      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" max-width="100%" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td>

            <!-- HEADER -->
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" max-width="100%" align="center">
              <tr align="center">
                <td>
                  <p>Is this email not displaying correctly? <a href="#" text-decoration="none">View this email in your web browser</p></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- END HEADER -->

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`text-decoration` is a [CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-text-decoration), not an [HTML attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#attributes-1).

[It has to go in a style sheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started) or [a `style` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-style-attribute).

This, among various other errors, would be picked up if you used [a markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Comment: Do you mean I should have it as
`<td style="text-decoration: none;">`?

Comment: No, because it is the *link* that has an underline by default, not the entire content of the table data cell.

Comment: I tried what I just posted in the anchor tag, which seemed to work. I also added `<style></style>` to the head, to add other styles as well. I was shown a different way to do it without having `style="text-decoration: none;"` the way I do, so that's really what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Quentin is right:

- `text-decoration` is indeed a CSS property therefore it has to be called via the `style` attribute.
- also, that `style` attribute has to go inside the tag that it is referencing. Table cells are not `div`s so inheritance (generally speaking) does not work the same way.

Finally, a suggestion. Write your CSS as you would normally do inside the `<style>` tags and then convert it into inline with [inliner](http://zurb.com/ink/inliner.php).

Answer (score -1):

If you want it completely gone, you have to remove the underline in all four pseudo-classes (link, hover, active, and visited), which you can only do with CSS.

See this [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) tutorial for info about pseudo-classes in CSS.

Comment: That isn't true. Author stylesheets trump browser stylesheets even if with less specific selectors … and an inline style is more specific that any number of pseudo-classes anyway.